# camel - how to have multiple contexts with java config

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to group several camel routes in different camel contexts to avoid component name clashing. I know how to configure several RouteBuilder classes in the same Context extending From CamelConfiguration this way

```
   @Configuration
   public class CamelConfig extends CamelConfiguration {

   @Override
   public List<RouteBuilder> routes() {
       // here I create the RouteBuilder List and the return it
   }
```

But how I can have some routes in one camel context and other routes in other camel context using Java Configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can add many **Camel Routes** defined in **external XML files** in just one **Camel Context**
as the example bellow:

You can create your routes in a new xml file (ie. *routes1-config.xml*):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
">

  <!-- this is an included XML file where we only the the routeContext -->
  <routeContext id="routes1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <!-- we can have a route -->
    <route id="cool">
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </route>
    <!-- and another route, you can have as many your like -->
    <route id="bar">
        <from uri="direct:bar"/>
        <to uri="mock:bar"/>
    </route>
  </routeContext>

</beans>
```

and then import and reference it on the context inside the main camel xml file, like this:

```
<!-- import the routes from another XML file -->
<import resource="routes1-config.xml"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

  <!-- refer to a given route to be used -->
  <routeContextRef ref="routes1"/>

  <!-- we can of course still use routes inside camelContext -->
  <route id="inside">
    <from uri="direct:inside"/>
    <to uri="mock:inside"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

For more details please check the official reference documentation from Apache Camel http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-import-routes-from-other-xml-files.html

Answer (score 0):

one `CamelConfiguration` class creates one `CamelContext`. The solution is to have multiple such sub classes (or similar).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Petter! But how can I do this? Basically I have a property file where I define a list of the RouteBuilder classes. And then the code in routes iterate that file. What I'd like to have is the same file with the list of RouterBuilder classes but create each RouteBuilder inside its own Camel Context. Is that possible? Maybe modifying the CamelConfiguration class in some way but I'm not sure how to do it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use NMR (Normalized Message Router), http://camel.apache.org/nmr.html and expose the routes in each of those projects camel configuration as NMR routes and then consume it through your unified Java method using nmr:routename.